# Minimum Resources to Download / Install OSX on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Given a 2012 MacBook Air sold without an SSD, what would need to be on a replacement SSD to be installed in the MBA?  The goal is to have enough resources on the machine to download and install OSX?

For those providing answers, do not assume the reader has experience installing operating systems: please provide at least a reference (hyperlink) to the steps associated with your answer.  Thank you

Update: perhaps there is a method to place the OS install files on the replacement SSD (maybe it own partition is necessary), install and somehow prompt the install process?

Comment: Usually nothing, except an active WiFi-Router connected to the Internet and the WiFi password ☞ Internet Recovery

Comment: I would just [create a bootable installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) on a USB drive.

Comment: @red_menace  I think that bootable installer is an interesting option and invite you to post an answer that provides more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Usually nothing is required to install macOS except an active WiFi-Router connected to the Internet with DHCP enabled and its WiFi password.

After turning on the Mac and immediately pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> the MacBook Air should boot to macOS Recovery over the Internet (earlier "Internet Recovery") (Apple Support: [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)). You will be asked for a WiFi password.

If macOS Recovery over the Internet works you should see a spinning globe and depending on your Internet speed you will see the Recovery console sooner or later.

The console contains several tools including *Disk Utility* and *Reinstall macOS*

Disk Utility is required to partition and format the SSD. Later choose Reinstall macOS to install a new system.

If the above shortcut doesn't work you can try to press and hold <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd><kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd><kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd><kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

The different boot and install options are outlined here: [Learn more about these key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).

---

To improve user experience I would ask the future (unexperienced) user which system he/she/* would like to have and simply download and install it up to the configuration screen (like Apple does with new Macs).

Comment: Is macOS recovery built into the computer EEPROM and not the hard drive?  If so it would seem like a good test for the MBA without SSD.  MacBook model is TBD.  Excellent answer

Comment: It depends: if the disk contains a (working) recovery partition it will boot from the local disk with the first shortcut. If no disk is available it will boot from an Apple supplied network boot image (AFAIR via bootpd). I just have to test this with my broken iMac (no working disks inside) I'm using right now ;-)